# wifi doesn't work directly on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point

I have Ubuntu 18.04 in my PC together with Windows 10.  When the WiFi works on Windows and I restart the computer to Ubuntu, the WiFi is OK even in Ubuntu. But when the computer is shuted down and I start with Ubuntu, there is apparently no way to start the WiFi. Can someone help me to make the WiFi available in Ubuntu directly?

I typed inxi -F as recommended  in comments and the result is as follows:

```
System:    Host: kouty-ThinkCentre-M720q Kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64
           bits: 64
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: un-determined System: LENOVO product: 10T7004NIV v: ThinkCentre M720q serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 312D v: SDK0J40697 WIN 3305169475212 serial: N/A
           UEFI: LENOVO v: M1UKT47A date: 08/14/2019
CPU:       6 core Intel Core i5-8400T (-MCP-) cache: 9216 KB
           clock speeds: max: 3300 MHz 1: 3200 MHz 2: 3192 MHz 3: 3106 MHz
           4: 3288 MHz 5: 3105 MHz 6: 3105 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 3e92
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 ) driver: i915
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8
Audio:     Card Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.0.0-37-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V driver: e1000e
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: e8:6a:64:2d:a4:ee
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi
           IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: 50:76:af:56:b2:60
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 256.1GB (3.5% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: SanDisk_SD9TB8W2 size: 256.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 59G used: 8.4G (16%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 46.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 253 Uptime: 2 min Memory: 1248.8/7844.9MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Further I opened the "Show applications" and typed wifi and they say me I have "no wifi adapter found". So I restarted and opened Windows, the wifi started to work. I restarted again and opened Ubuntu and I have a good wifi. If I turn it off, I can "no more connect  because "no wifi adapter found". Can someone explain me how I can install the right wifi adapter. I seen a lot of posts here and Ubuntu documentation, and don't know what is the right procedure.

The kernel version is Linux 5.3.0-28-generic
**I understand that I need some WiFi adapter congruent with Card-2: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi**

Update following the advise of @pilot6. I typed when the wifi doesn't work

```
kouty@kouty-ThinkCentre-M720q:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:1010]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
[    4.098054] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.191186] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Comment: it seems that your problem is not a isolated issue for dual boot windows/ubuntu so please provide the output from this command `inxi -F`. Cheers!

Comment: it seems that your problem is not a isolated issue for dual boot windows/ubuntu so please provide the output from this command inxi -F. Cheers!

Comment: When the WiFi does not start at that point can you also list the output of rfkill. It might be that when Windows shut down, it might be hard blocking the adapter.

Comment: I don't know what is rfkill

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; dmesg | grep iwl` terminal command. Run it when Wi-Fi deosn't work.

Comment: Try re-starting your system manager: sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Comment: @Pilot6 I will try this first.

Comment: Try what? Install kernel 4.14? That's a really bad idea. That command will show what is the problem.

Comment: No I need to check following your recommendation and edit the question.

Comment: @Pilot6 I edited the question.

Comment: This is a kernel bug, or a harware failure.

Comment: Is it solvable? Perhaps this Ubuntu version isn't good. Did you know how to fix it? @Pilot6

Comment: I don't know how to fix it. I suggest reporting a bug by running `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: @Pilot I forced upgrade by `update-manager -d` I hope this help now it will be Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just open windows 10, then open a command prompt in administrator mode (right click of the mouse) and write:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

It's because Windows 10 is not really shut down but in an hibernate mode.

Have a good day ;)

Comment: But when I changed version it works

Comment: Hi, I got similar issue win10 + ubuntu18.04, I din't check the wifi  like you, so I don't know if my problem was really similar to yours, but every time I shut down my computer and I start on ubuntu I got no wifi, and I must restart the computer to have it. You can try if you have time, or if you want an older version of ubuntu to downgrade to 18.04 and then do what I said. Do as you please :)

Comment: This answer is the right, thanks so much. After uprgading ubuntu, after a few days, the problem comes back, perhaps when I updated windows 10. Then, I followed your recommendations and the wifi works fine in Ubuntu. thank's again, I am sorry that both I and you lost the points of the bounty.

Comment: Thanks You Very Much :)

Answer (score 1):

I was informed by @Pilot6 that the problem was a kernel bug or a hardware failure.

Finally, I forced upbrade to Ubuntu 20.04 by

```
update-manager –d
```

following [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-update-kernel-ubuntu) link, ad now the wifi works correctly.

The kernel version has been changed to Linux 5.4.0-12-generic

Answer (score 0):

From [Linux Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=243925) you need to upgrade your kernel. They recommend 4.10 but personally I like`4.14` because it has five years of support: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

Comment: Since I am not a specialist and cannot judge answers, I want to follow your answer according to your reputation. I searched the updates and go to `Index of /~kernel-ppa/mainline` but I am not able to find there the 4.10 or 4.14

Comment: I found `v4.14.168 mainline build` but after typing it there is a whole page of "build for" and I don't now what to choose.

Comment: my kernel version is Linux 5.3.0-28-generic

Comment: On the link if you scroll down to my answer it shows you which items to click on. 5.3 kernel may have broken wifi but I honestly don't know at this time.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has minimum 4.15 kernel. HWE is 5.3 now. Why would you sugeest the 4.14.mainline? It can only break things.

Comment: Because it works fine for me. As I said it's a personal preference. If it's not broken don't upgrade the heart of the machine.

Comment: It works fine on another OS, that is using mush older kernels.

Comment: @Pilot6 It's a matter of personal preference using a Linux Mainline/Stable Kernel that is LTS rather than a Ubuntu versioned kernel. I find it easier to get documentation on the internet on what changes weekly from the kernel developers. Then when I feel like it I pull in a kernel update based upon what I've read. I only do this every couple/few months at my convenience and it is not pushed onto my machine by Ubuntu updates. Because the Linux Mint forum says 4.10 works and OP says 5.0 doesn't work (possibly regression) I suggested 4.14 which is LTS kernel.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Odd choice indeed, and I am not sure the OP is skilled enough to do the same.

Comment: @mikewhatever It's really not that difficult to download and install a mainline stable kernel. Additionally `ukuu` can be used if you want a GUI approach. Indeed if it is a kernel related issue the hardest part is reading docs to find out where it was fixed and broken.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Compiling kernels, as that is what you have to do with 4.14, is a major PITA and a wast of time, IMHO. It takes forever, and mainly, I don't think it applies to this question.

Comment: @mikewhatever No Ubuntu has a kernel farm where they grow 4.14 LTS mainline stable kernels and other LTS and short term Linux kernels. You don't need to compile it. See the second link in the answer.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Bingo, got it.